# VBA: Getting a reference value from another sheet as a criteria for filter

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets - "Criteria" and "temporary".

I want to apply filter in Criteria sheet where the criteria will be taken from the active cell of "temporary" sheet. My below macro is failing for some reason.

```
Sub FilterTest1()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "temporary"

ActiveSheet.[A:A].Value = Worksheets("Criteria").[A:A].Value

Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

Range("A1").EntireRow.Delete

Dim B As Integer
B = Cells.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With Sheets("Temporary")
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
End With


With Sheets("Criteria")

.Range("$A:$B").AutoFilter
   .Range("$A:$B").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets("temporary").ActiveCell.Value, Operator:=xlOr

End With

End Sub
```

The macro ends with a

> run time error 438 "Object doesnt support this property or method.

whats the right method to do?

Adding further info: the objective is to change the criteria one by one. Right now it should select the last active cell in Temporary!A:A but then later i would be offsetting the selection upwards in Temporary!A:A and will be taking each active cell sheet as a criteria for filtering.

Comment: In which line does the error occur? • Note: Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle: It is recommended [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The error is on the 3rd row from bottom where the criteria is mentioned

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to apply the last value in Temporary!A:A to a var than rely on Select and Selection.

However, all,of your code seems to boil down to the AutoFilter taking the last value in Criteria!A:A as the filter. Adding a new worksheet, copying over the values from Criteria!A:A, removing duplicates and then selecting the last populated cell in Temporary!A:A does nothing to change that. If you sorted the data in Temporary!A:A it might change, but nothing you are currently doing is changing the criteria from the populated last value in Criteria!A:A.

```
Sub FilterTest1()
    dim c as variant
    with workSheets("Criteria")
        c = .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).value
        .Range("A:B").AutoFilter  field:=1, Criteria1:=c
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. the objective is to change the criteria one by one. Right now it should select the last active cell but then later i would be offsetting the selection upwards in Temporary!A:A and will be taking each active cell as a criteria for filtering. There will be further processing after filtering.

Comment: Build a dictionary of the unique values in column A and cycle through the dictionary keys to filter each in turn. Many examples available here; several attributed to me.

Comment: Hi as per your suggestion i have been searching for this all over the google since last few days, but i am not able to get relevant info. Could you please share a link which would be useful for this case?